# Image referencing inside a NB project?

Tags: java, image, netbeans, reference

Ok, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but I am not able to reference images in my NB Java project. My code is basically the same as this:

```
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("Resources/character.png");
```

I Have a package called Resources in my src, and character.png in that package, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: give the path from the project root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is within the class path (eg. `<project>/src/Resources/character.png`), load it as [***resource***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-):

Here's an example:

```
public class Example
{
    public ImageIcon loadImage()
    {
        // Note the '/'
        final String path = "/Resources/character.png"; 

        // Load the image as a resource
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(path));

        // Return the result
        return icon;
    }
}

// ...

Example e = new Example();
ImageIcon icon = e.loadImage();
```